# RobotFramework Python Get Text from inside a javascript function

Tags: python, css, selenium, robotframework

The below alert text inside the pasted function below only appears when I hit a button.
I wish to capture the text to validate it.

When I use the following code I can find the locator on the page, but no text is returned in my response.
How can I get inside the function?

```
${response}    Get Text    css=body script:nth-child(9)

(script)
        $(function () {
            Metro.toast.create("No changes have been entered so 
                   nothing will be updated in CMS!", null, 6000, "alert");
        });
 (/script)
```

The response comes as pass but with no text.

`15:49:17.350   INFO    ${response} =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get Text` in Selenium/SeleniumLibrary returns the *visible* text in a tag - e.g. what the browser renders in the viewport. Naturally, anything that is in a `<script>` is not that - it's code that will be executed *(regardless what it'll do - put some text out there or not, it is code)*.

You can still get the tag's content though - every DOM element has an attribute `innerHTML`, that is its raw content *(before rendering and so on)*. So try this:

```
${response}    Get Element Attribute   css=body script:nth-child(9)    innerHTML
```

This will of course return you everything (because the response is the raw content) - `"Metro.toast.create("`, etc - so you'll have to manipulate the output a bit, to get just the method's argument.